# How to compile free-form and fixed-form Fortran codes with ifort in linux

Tags: makefile, fortran

I try to compile free-form Fortran code  (param0.f90, param1.f90, and  param2.f90), in which contains alot of parameters for tsunami modelling. There is only single main program in fixed-form  (tunami.for) in this model package. I am struggling to compile and link the code by using the makefile. Here the makefile that I used.

```
#-----------BEGIN MAKEFILE------------------------------------------------- 
         DEF_FLAGS     = -P -traditional 
         EXEC          = TUNAMI
#==========================================================================
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#        PRECISION          DEFAULT PRECISION: SINGLE                     
#                           UNCOMMENT TO SELECT DOUBLE PRECISION
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#         FLAG_1 = -DDOUBLE_PRECISION
#         FLAG_2 = -DPARALLEL
#         FLAG_3 = -DLANDSLIDE
#         FLAG_4 = -DSALINITY
#         FLAG_5 = -DTEMPERATURE
#         FLAG_6 = -DBUBBLE
#         FLAG_7 = -DSEDIMENT
#         FLAG_8 = -DVEGETATION
         FLAG_9 = -DINTEL
#     FLAG_10 = -DBALANCE2D
#    FLAG_12 = -DTWOLAYERSLIDE
#    FLAG_13 = -DCORALREEF
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  mpi defs 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
         CPP      = /usr/bin/cpp 
         CPPFLAGS = $(DEF_FLAGS)
#         FC       = ifort
         FC        = ifort
         DEBFLGS  = 
         OPT      = #-g
         CLIB     = 
#==========================================================================
         FFLAGS = $(DEBFLGS) $(OPT) 
         MDEPFLAGS = --cpp --fext=f90 --file=-
         RANLIB = ranlib
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  CAT Preprocessing Flags
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
         CPPARGS = $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEF_FLAGS) $(FLAG_1) $(FLAG_2) $(FLAG_3) \
                   $(FLAG_4) $(FLAG_5) $(FLAG_6) $(FLAG_7) $(FLAG_8) $(FLAG_9) \
               $(FLAG_10) $(FLAG_11) $(FLAG_12) $(FLAG_13)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Libraries           
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
         LIBS  = -L/home/gugum/Downloads/hypre/src/hypre/lib -lHYPRE
         INCS  = -L/home/gugum/Downloads/hypre/src/hypre/include
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Preprocessing and Compilation Directives
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
.SUFFIXES: .o .f90 .F .F90

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCS) $*.c

.F.o:
    $(CPP) $(CPPARGS) $(PETSC_FC_INCLUDES) $*.F > $*.f90
    $(FC)  -c $(FFLAGS) $(INCS) $*.f90
    \rm $*.f90

.F90.o:
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CPPDEFS) $(INCLDIR) $< > $*.f  
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $(FIXEDFLAGS) $(INCS) $(INCLDIR) $*.f  
    \rm $*.f90
#   \rm $*.f90
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  NHWAVE Source Code.
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

MODS  = param0.f90  param1.f90 param2.f90 

MAIN  = TUNAMI.for
   
SRCS = $(MODS)  $(MAIN)

#OBJS = $(SRCS:.F=.o) param0.o param1.o param2.o
OBJS = $(patsubst %.for,%.o,$(patsubst %.f90,%.o,$(SRCS)))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Linking Directives               
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

$(EXEC):    $(OBJS)
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Cleaning targets.
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

clean:
        /bin/rm -f *.o *.mod

clobber:    clean
        /bin/rm -f *.f90 *.o tunami
```

However, it produces an error.

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'param0.o', needed by 'TUNAMI'. Stop.
```

Comment: Which rule do you think applies to generate a `.o` file from a `.f90` (not `.F90`) file?

Comment: Sorry can you please expand a bit? I am new to this makefile things.

Comment: Few comments: (1) The rule to compile .F90 to .o will remove the source code if the FC builds works. (2) There is no need to quote the `rm` with `\rm`. (3) the INCS is using -L, should probably use -I.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ifort in particular, and not much to do even with Fortran in general.

Comment: It is odd that your `.F.o` rule uses intermediate files with extension `.f90`, whereas your `.F90.o` rule uses intermediate files with extension `.f`.  Surely that's backwards?

Comment: Additionally, if you really do have sources with extensions `.F` and / or `.F90` that you want to run through the C preprocessor, then it would be better `make` form to write a `.F.f` rule and a `.F90.f90` rule that perform the preprocessing, plus a `.f.o` and `.f90.o` if the built in versions do not suffice.  Aside from being cleaner and better factored, that will have the advantage that (GNU) `make` will clean up the intermediate files for you automatically.